# Calculating 7 day p95 of latency for system performance to external users

Tags: prometheus, promql, victoriametrics

Hey folks I'm looking for some help validating my approach and any corrections if necessary.

A quick explanation of my requirement: We provide a dashboard that shows the last 7 days latency performance of our system to end users. That is in an ideal world take all requests served in the last 7 days and construct a histogram of their latencies. Followed by p95 of the latencies.

`rate()[7d]` would not have served our requirement as it takes just the first and last scrape in `7d` window and focuses on providing a smooth slop by averaging the delta between these 2 points.

Option 1

Using `histogram_over_time`

So I have broken it down into 3 steps

1. Derive p95 of a `1m` window initially using `rate`, `sum`, and  `histogram_quantile`.
2. VictoriaMetrics's `histogram_over_time` works on raw values; use `histogram_over_time` to now construct a histogram on p95 latencies calculated via #1 point
3. Using #2 histogram calculate the p95 over `7d`

Here's the final metric that is constructed which is p95 of p95

```
histogram_quantile(0.95, histogram_over_time(histogram_quantile(0.95, sum(rate(latency_bucket[1m])) by (le))[7d]))
```

Option 2

Using `sum_over_time`

1. Get the sum of all buckets across machines over a 7 day window - `sum_over_time(sum(rate(latency_bucket)) by (le) [1d])`
2. calculate the p99 of the histogram from #1

Final Metric

```
histogram_quantile(0.95, sum_over_time(sum(rate(latency_bucket)) by (le) [7d]))
```

Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `latency` [histogram](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#histogram) with multiple `latency_bucket` buckets, then the following query would return 95th [percentile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile) for the latency over all the requests during the last 7 days:

```
histogram_quantile(0.95, sum(increase(latency_bucket[7d])) by (le))
```

This query works in the following way:

1. It calculates the per-bucket number of hits over the last 7 days with `increase(latency_bucket[7d]))` . See [increase() docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#increase).
2. It sums buckets with identical `le` labels with `sum(...) by (le)` - see [sum() docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#sum). There may be multiple buckets with the same `le` if the `latency_bucket` is collected from multiple targets with distinct `instance` label. For example, `latency_bucket{le="0.5",instance="host1"}` and `latency_bucket{le="0.5",instance="host2"}`.
3. It calculates 95th percentile over the buckets returned at the previous step with `histogram_quantile(0.95, ...)` - see [histogram_quantile() docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#histogram_quantile).